# Focusing input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can't focus input field with jQuery. I've tried :
$('input').first().focus()
on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Could you wirite a snippet that will do what I want on the page mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

try out

```
$('input.form-control[type=text]').first().focus();
```